# Aligning objects that are embedded in a NSBox

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, alignment, nsbox

I'm trying to align different objects (labels, textfields, ...) to one another within a NSBox. I can align them relative to the NSBox, but not e.g. two labels horizontally or properly spaced.
Is there a setting or anything else I can do? Kind of tedious to first unembedd, get rid of the box and then re-embedd.

Comment: Might be easier to explain what you are trying to do if you included a screenshot.  Also, are you using AutoLayout or are you using the older Springs & Struts in your storyboard or XIB?

Comment: I don't think there is any value in a screenshot. Put a NSBox in a View and try to horizontally align e.g. two labels or properly space them apart. Using AutoLayout.